# perl not clearing data on page exit

Tags: perl

sorry if the title doesn't make much sense, I'll explain.

I am learning Perl, which I have to use at work, so am running test programs. I am inputting data into a web form (name, age, location) and searching a MySQL database to find a match. When I search it returns any matching results printed on the screen. However, if I go back to the form and search again, knowing that the result will not be found, it just displays the last found record and I can't quite figure out why.

Can someone help me please?

Thanks in advance.

```
# Read the standard input (sent by the form):
read(STDIN, $FormData, $ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'});
# Get the name and value for each form input:
@pairs = split(/&/, $FormData);
# Then for each name/value pair....
$db = DBI->connect($conn->DataSource(), $conn->Username(), $conn->Password()) or die "Unable to connect: $DBI::errstr\n";
foreach $pair (@pairs) 
{
    # Separate the name and value:
($name, $value) = split(/=/, $pair);
#replace + with space as + means space when data is collected
$value =~ tr/+/ /;
$value =~ s/%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])/pack("C", hex($1))/eg;
# Store values in a hash called %FORM:
$FORM{$name} = $value;
}
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM person WHERE Name = '".$FORM{'PName'}."' AND Age = '".$FORM{'Age'}."' AND Location = '".$FORM{'Location'}."'");
$query->execute();
# BIND TABLE COLUMNS TO VARIABLES
$query->bind_columns(undef, \$name, \$age, \$location);
# LOOP THROUGH RESULTS
$row = 0;
while($query->fetch())
{
push @Peeps, Person->New();
$Peeps[$row]->Name($name);
$Peeps[$row]->Age($age);
$Peeps[$row]->Location($location);
$row++;
}
$db->disconnect(); #disconnect from the db

print '<table>';
for($i = 0; $i <= $#Peeps; $i++)
{
    print "<tr><td>$Peeps[$i]{'NAME'}</td><td>$Peeps[$i]{'AGE'}</td><td>$Peeps[$i]{'LOCATION'}</td></tr>";
}
print '</table>';
$db->disconnect(); #disconnect from the db
```

Comment: I assume you're writing a web page driven by a perl script. This sounds more like a browser caching issue than anything else.

Comment: Why not use the CGI module? it simplifies a lot your code!

Comment: Your code has some extremely serious security issues and other problems. Before you do anything else, you need to throw away whatever learning material you're using and get a good (free) book like [Modern Perl](http://onyxneon.com/books/modern_perl/) or check out these [Perl Tutorial](http://perl-tutorial.org/) resources.

Comment: Cheers, guys I'll take a look at the CGI module and see how it goes. I know the code is poor, it is just a really basic implementation, but I'll check out those resources, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using mod_perl or fastcgi where the server process is persistent over multiple requests, global variables (which you are using in your example) may not be reset between requests, but keep their old values.

In your example, this means that the next request may see the `%FORM` values set by the earlier request, if the request happens to come to the same server process.

If by adding `%FORM = ();` at the top of your script fixes the problem, then this is your issue. You can verify by saying e.g. `print $test++;` and see if it increments.

Note that this is not the real solution, I would recommend putting your real code inside a function or module and using local variables and parameters there, it is more maintainable as well. And using some of the web application frameworks available (minimally CGI.pm).

You also need to fix the SQL injection security problem, *rule of thumb: Never put variables in SQL statement strings*, but do something like:

```
$dbh->prepare("SELECT ... WHERE This = ? AND That = ?")
$dbh->execute($this, $that);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the question is too generic and for any useful answer, a bit of code/pseudo code is going to be essential. However, based entirely on what you've asked, it does look like a browser caching issue, or perhaps a session-data caching issue. Like I say, disclosing a bit of code / pseudo code will help understand your question better

Comment: I have tried clearing the browser cache manually and that made no difference, is session data caching not cleared at the same time?

Comment: I've added a code sample above